# delete file loop error

Tags: c#, image, delete-file

I have created loops to create chart images from my datagridviews. I made each image individualy and then I merged them

```
Image img = new Bitmap(1024, 1200);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);

            g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("chart" + i + ".png"), new System.Drawing.Point(0, 100));

            g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("chart2" + i + ".png"), new System.Drawing.Point(0, 600));

            img.Save("finalchart-" + i + ".png");
```

Now I wanted to delete those individual charts and leave only "finalchart". So I've made another loop to delete individual charts.

```
for (j = 1; j < columnCount; j++)
        {


           System.IO.File.Delete("chart" + j + ".png");
           System.IO.File.Delete("chart2" + j + ".png");
        }
```

But when I start my program I get this error:

> The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Frosty\Desktop\program\aproximator\program\program\bin\Debug\chart3.png'
>   because it is being used by another process.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You should dispose `Image`

Comment: you have to dispose your objects. wrap your code in ``using (Image img = new Bitmap(1024, 1200)) { using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img)) { //your code } }``

Answer (score 0):

As long as `img` has a reference, it will hold onto these other handles.  Just dispose of it at the end:

```
Image img = new Bitmap(1024, 1200);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("chart" + i + ".png"), new System.Drawing.Point(0, 100));
g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("chart2" + i + ".png"), new System.Drawing.Point(0, 600));
img.Save("finalchart-" + i + ".png");
img.Dispose(); // like one commenter mentioned
```